# Sending javascript variable from view to controller in Codeigniter by POST method but in controller post aaray showing empty

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Sending javascript variable by post method from view to controller of Codeigniter but when i access it in controller post array showing empty.

type: "POST",
method:"POST", both are not working

My view

```
<input type="month" id="reg_month" name="reg_month" onchange="sort_by_reg_month()" class="form-control" placeholder="Month of Reg Users" autofocus="autofocus">
```

my javascript code

```js
//sort student by month of registration
  function sort_by_reg_month(){ 
    var reg_month = $('#reg_month').val();

    if(reg_month)
    {  
     $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url().'Users/get_user_sort_by_reg_month'; ?>", 
      method:"POST",
      data:{ 
            "reg_month":reg_month
            }, 
      success:function(data)
      { 
       alert('Student sorted by reg_month.');
      },
      error: function() {
                alert('Something is wrong...');

             }
     });
    }
  location.reload();
  }
```

```php
//controller Users
//sort student by geristration month

public function get_user_sort_by_reg_month(){
    $reg_month = $this->input->post('reg_month'); 
    var_dump($reg_month);
    if ($reg_month) {       
      $time=strtotime($reg_month);
      $month=date("F",$time);
      $year=date("Y",$time);
      $result['users'] = $this->Users_model->sort_by_reg_month($month,$year);
    }else{
      $result['users'] = $this->Users_model->get_user();
    }
```

Want to access post data but showing an empty array

Comment: first, check your console.see ajax request goes to that page or not .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
url:"<?php echo base_url().'Users/get_user_sort_by_reg_month'; ?>"
```

Maximum that you could append to this line is `index.php`, but, if you've removed it via `config` and `.htaccess`, then you need to append nothing. It means next:

```
url:"Users/get_user_sort_by_reg_month"
```

or

```
url:"index.php/Users/get_user_sort_by_reg_month"
```

Check this out, it works for me.
If you'll need my working example, I'll present it to you here.

My example:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="month" 
        id="reg_month" 
        name="reg_month" 
        onchange="sort_by_reg_month();" 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Month of Reg Users" 
        autofocus="autofocus"
        />
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {

//sort student by month of registration

}); 

  function sort_by_reg_month(){ 

        var reg_month = $('#reg_month').val();

    if(reg_month)
    {  
     $.ajax({
      url:"index.php/page_work/get_user_sort_by_reg_month", 
      method:"POST",
      data:{ 
            "reg_month":reg_month
            }, 
      success:function(data)
      { 
      // var_dump from php
      //  alert(data);
        alert('Student sorted by reg_month.');
      },
      error: function() {
                alert('Something is wrong...');

             }
     });
    } 
  // I don't need it (because it reloads page and I'll not see the result)
  // location.reload();
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function get_user_sort_by_reg_month(){

    $reg_month = $this->input->post('reg_month'); 
    return var_dump($reg_month);
    /*
    if ($reg_month) {   

      $time=strtotime($reg_month);
      $month=date("F",$time);
      $year=date("Y",$time);
      $result['users'] = $this->Users_model->sort_by_reg_month($month,$year);
    }else{
      $result['users'] = $this->Users_model->get_user();
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but look I have do call to controller function successfully but not able to access post data. post array showing empty its my main problem. please can you share your working example.